# How to invoke function based on condition of iterated value of Mono<List<String>> without using subscribe()?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to invoke a function that will notify the admin about some information missing, but I do not want to subscribe to this Mono, because I will subscribe to it later. The problem is I have some log which is called inside *doOnSuccess()* and when I use *subscribe()* and then build a response where I zip *listOfWords* value, the same log is logged twice and I do not want a code to behave that way.

Is there any way to retrieve that value in *checkCondition()* in a way that will not invoke *doOnSuccess()* or should I use some other function in *merge()* that can replace *doOnSuccess()*?

Should I use *subscribe()* only once on given Mono or is it allowed to use it multiple times?

Thank you in advance!

The functions are called in the presented order.

Code where log is called:

```
private fun merge(list1: Mono<List<String>>, list2: Mono<List<String>>) =
    Flux.merge(
        list1.flatMapMany { Flux.fromIterable(it) },
        list2.flatMapMany { Flux.fromIterable(it) }
    )
        .collectList()
        .doOnSuccess { LOG.debug("List of words: $it") }
```

Code where subscribe is called:

```
private fun checkCondition(
    listOfWords: Mono<List<String>>,
) {
    listOfWords.subscribe {
        it.forEach { word ->
            if (someCondition(word)) {
                alarmSystem.notify("Something is missing for word {0}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code where response is built:

```
private fun buildResponse(
    map: Mono<Map<String, String>>,
    list1: List<SomeObject>,
    listOfWords: Mono<List<String>>
): Mono<List<Answer>> {
    val response = Mono.zip(map, Mono.just(list1), listOfWords)
        .map { tuple ->
            run {
                val tupleMap = tuple.t1
                val list = tuple.t2
                val words = tuple.t3
                list
                    .filter { someCondition(words) }
                    .map { obj -> NewObject(x,y) }
            }
        }
```

Comment: do not subscribe anywhere in your application. The calling client is the subscriber. You should never subscribe unless you application is the final consumer. Why are you subscribing just to print something? if you want to print something, use `doOnNext` which is specifically used for side effects. Mono and fluxes are producers, and the one that is going to consume is the subscriber... the client

Comment: Thank you, I do not know why, but doOnNext does not work for me. But I sorted this out.

Comment: please post and show us instead of saying "it doesn't work", subscribing in a application could hinder performance a lot.